# How to disable n or ac mode aircrack

Tags: aircrack-ng, airodump-ng

I am unable to see clients connected to an ap when using airodump. After extensive research i have found that it’s because my adapter is using 802.11n. n mode doesn’t work when capturing, neither does ac. I know that my adapter being the alfa awuso36nha supports other modes like g mode. How do i change the modes in linux?